# Where is $\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

My notes say that it is the complement of $[-1,1]$.
However, this is what I got:

(The square root function is the principal value function)

$\sqrt{f(z)}$ is analytic on the complement of the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Re{f(z)}\leq 0 \wedge \Im{f(z)
} = 0\}$.

So,
$\sqrt{z+1}$ is not analytic when $\Re(z+1) = \Re(z) + 1 \leq 0 \implies \Re(z) \leq -1$.
$\sqrt{z-1}$ is not analytic when $\Re(z-1) = \Re(z) - 1 \leq 0 \implies \Re(z) \leq 1$.
So,
$\sqrt{z+1}\sqrt{z-1}$ is not analytic on the union of this... that is, when $\Re(z) \leq 1$.
So it is analytic on the complement of $\{z\in\mathbb{R}:z\leq 1$}.

Am I correct here?

Comment: First, you have written "$\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re z \leq 0 \wedge \Im z = 0\}$, but you have used "$\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re f(z) \leq 0 \wedge \Im f(z) = 0\}$.  Second, why would you not apply this criterion to $f(z) = (z-1)(z+1) = z^2 - 1$?

Comment: I didn't apply it there because I wasn't sure whether or not $\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1} = \sqrt{z^2-1}$

Answer (score 3):

The branch cuts that you identified each represent a sign change in the function value. Note that the root function is defined there. At places where both factors are on its branch cut, the two sign changes combine to a multiplication to $1$, so that there is no discontinuity in the product. As a function is defined via its function values, the discontinuity in intermediate steps does not count if it vanishes in the final result.

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old post, but are you saying that the branch cut for $x\leq -1$ essentially cancels out (hence the function may still be differentiable here)? I was literally about to submit the same question, before finding this thread.

Comment: Yes, both factors change the sign simultaneously when going from $Im(z)\ge 0$ to $Im(z)<0$, resulting in a smooth change in the product. But you'd have to be careful to use this factorization for any further computation, for instance for the product rule of differentiation. Then it would be better to conclude that $z\sqrt{1-z^{-1}}$ represents the same function on the given domain.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You're correct that it's analytic where both $\sqrt{z+1}$ and $\sqrt{z-1}$ are analytic since the product of two analytic functions is analytic. But it's not true that it need to be non-analytic elsewhere.

Your conclusion is correct, but not the entire truth. You need to further investigate the behaviour of the function for real numbers $\le 1$.

First of all you have that for positive real numbers the principal square root is analytic and for nonpositive it's non-analytic. So if one of $z+1$ and $z-1$ is positive and the other not the product will be non-analytic so for $-1\le z\le 1$ it will certainly be non-analytic.

Finally we have to consider $z<-1$. By considering the cases $\Im z\ge0$ and $\Im z<0$ we see that $\sqrt{z+1}\sqrt{z-1} = \sqrt{z^2-1}$ if $\Re z<-1$ which means that it's analytic there too.

So the entire truth is that it's analytic on the complement of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, in your second last paragraph, why does  
$$\sqrt{z+1}\sqrt{z-1}=\sqrt{z^2-1}$$ when $\Re{z}<-1$ imply that it's analytic for $\Re{z} <-1$?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is analytic except when $z^2-1\le0$ or $z^2 \le 1$ which can only happen when $|z|\le1$ which isn't possible when $\Re z < -1$

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$
f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}
$$
is analytic in any domain $\Omega$ with the following property:

*The points $-1$ and $1$ lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb C_\infty\smallsetminus\Omega$.*

Most typical such domains: $\Omega_1=\mathbb C\smallsetminus[-1,1]$ and $\Omega_2=\mathbb C\smallsetminus\big((-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)\big)$.

This is due to the following lemma:

**Lemma.** *If $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$ is an open region and $a,b\in\mathbb C$ lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb C_\infty\smallsetminus\Omega$, then $$f(z)=\log\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)$$ defines an analytic function in $\Omega$.*

Using this lemma, we may define
$$
\sqrt{z^2-1}=(z+1)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\Big(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\Big)\right).
$$

**Generalisation.** The function 
$$
f(z)=\sqrt[n]{z^n-1}
$$
is analytic in any domain $\Omega$ with the property that all the $n-$th root of 1
lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb C_\infty\smallsetminus\Omega$.